# Why does my model rewrite not run?

Tags: magento, model, url-rewriting

Can some configuration in the admin panel (or elsewhere) prevent a model rewrite from running?

This is the rewrite declaration in the module's config.xml:

```
  <global>
    <models>
      <cataloginventory>
        <rewrite>
          <stock_item>My_Mod_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item</stock_item>
        </rewrite>
      </cataloginventory>
    </models>
  </global>
```

The module **is** active - this is certain because other module code is running.

I overwrote the checkQuoteItemQty method from Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item, but it's checkQuoteItemQty from the parent class that is running, no idea why...

```
    class My_Mod_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item extends Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item
    {
        public function checkQuoteItemQty($qty, $summaryQty, $origQty = 0)
        {
           // this code is not running...
           exit('hello there');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1 to debugging any rewrite — attempt to manually instantiate an object from the class yourself, and ensure that **your** class is the one used.

```
$object = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
var_dump(get_class($object));
```

If the above doesn't output `My_Mod_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item`, check that your `config.xml` is correct, that your `Item.php` file is in the right folder, and finally, jump to the [`getGroupedClassName` method](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6631/can-not-override-sales-resouce-model-collection-class/6664#6664) and add enough debugging code to determine **why** Magento isn't seeing your rewrite.

Comment: Thanks. I put the `var_dump` at the bottom of index.php, turns out there's another module rewriting the same core model.

Comment: I have faced same issue 2-3 times, and I used to search class name text in whole source code that if some class extending original class or not. Now I have standard way to find out same. Thanks Alan Storm